# user is not being created in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a users collection in firestore once a user has been created using firebase authentication, the user details go there when i run this code, but nothing appears in the firestore console, what am I doing wrong? I'm not even getting any errors in the terminal

hi

```
export default class Register extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
};

state = {
    name:"",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    errorMessage: null
};

handleSignUp = () => {

    const usersRef = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('Users');
  
    firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(function(userCredential) {
      usersRef
        .doc(`${userCredential.user.uid}`)
        .set({
          firstName: this.state.name,
          uid: userCredential.user.uid
        })
        
  
      })
    .catch(error => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}))
}
```

Comment: The code here isn't checking to see if the call to set() succeeded.  It returns a promise.  Without examining the promise, you won't know if it actually worked.

Comment: but it doesn't come up in the firebase console so thats how I know if it doesn't work, how do i examine the promise? @DougStevenson

Comment: The same way you are examining the promise returned by createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: If you change `usersRef.doc(...)` to `return usersRef.doc(...)`, it'll add the promise to the chain that you've attached the `.catch()` to.

Comment: hi what does the promise do? I've changed it to return and still no errors come up and it doesn't show up in the firestore collections, I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. thank you:) @samthecodingman